# How to Multiply Matrices in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

How to multiply matrices in basic openGL without GLUT or other extension packages?
Say, I want to calculate the result of T*M, both T and M are matrices. How to implement it in openGL?

I know it is such function called **glMultMatrix*()**. But it only replace the current model matrix by the result. And it's not the way to calculate matrix directly.

Comment: Is your question limited to 4x4 matrices or do you want code for genaral sized matrix multiplication?

Comment: BTW: Why do you ask in the first place? Do you need extra perfomance and want the multiplication to be executed at the GPU? In that case I would rather try to do the multiplication using SSE or AVX (or whatever SIMD you have available.)

Comment: ogl is about rendering stuff not math.  get yourself some decent library for stuff like this http://glm.g-truc.net/

Comment: how to multiply matrices is left as an "exercise for the reader" with recent GL versions.

Comment: @oysteijo Cause ogl uses 4*4 matrix to handle transforming issue, so I think we limited it to 4*4 is enough. Thank you for all your answers and it can be resolved by the code provided by CantChooseUsernames. But I learned a lot about the principle of openGL. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

`glMultMatrix` and associated functions are deprecated (and removed from core profiles) in more recent versions of OpenGL. Instead use a library such as [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) for tasks such as matrix multiplication (and much more).

This is probably the way to go even if you want to continue using the fixed function pipeline (and a compatibility profile). You can use `glLoadMatrix` to upload the results to OpenGL and you'll be in better shape to move forward with the programmable pipeline (where you'll be using the same matrix to set a shader program uniform).

Answer (score 1):

What about (http://ideone.com/EsQkAR):

```
#include <iostream>

void Multiply(float N[4][4], float M[4][4], float Result[4][4])
{
    for (int I = 0; I < 4; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < 4; ++J)
        {
            float SumElements = 0.0f;
            for (int K = 0; K < 4; ++K)
            {
                SumElements += M[I][K] * N[K][J];
            }
            Result[I][J] = SumElements;
        }
    }
}

void Print(float mat[4][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    float N[4][4] = 
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    float M[4][4] = 
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    float Result[4][4];

    Multiply(N, M, Result);
    Print(Result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift and functional correct answer! But does't openGL have some build-in functions to do this work? Cause it's quite a common calculation.

Comment: @user3367705 Modern OpenGL doesn't have anything for matrix math.

Comment: It's a good answer. But, this is the Standard matrix multiplication and it will just slow you up.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to calculate the result of T*M, both T and M are matrices. How to implement it in openGL?

You don't because OpenGL is not a math library. OpenGL is a drawing API: You hand it some data (geometry, textures, ready to use matrices) and it will use that to draw pictures to your command. Anything else is outside the scope of OpenGL.

---

Legacy OpenGL has some matrix manipulation functions built-in, but apart from beginner's tutorials and simple programs hardly any serious programs did actually use them, even 15 years ago. The reason for that is, that most of the time you need those matrices also otherwise for things like collision detection, rigid body mechanics and such, and it hardly makes sense to keep around redundant copies. And legacy OpenGL's matrix API is cumbersome to work with.

Also note that performing a single 4×4 matrix-matrix multiplication is more efficiently done on the CPU than if you'd offload it to the GPU (if you have thousands of matrix multiplications to perform, all to the same program, that's a wholly different story).

The matrix math performed by legacy OpenGL was only about single instances of matrix calculations. So there's no computational benefit using them; heck the whole overhead of going into the OpenGL implementation actually acts like a speed bump.